# How to Proxy Pass from / to /index.html

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm currently working on a JS Project, that uses the url path. Now if I go on my website with ***example.com/***, the JavaScript won't work, because I actually need ***example.com/index.html***.

I'm already using an reverse proxy to proxy pass to two different docker containers. So my idea was to pass the request to ***example.com/index.html*** when ***example.com/*** is called. But I can't figure out the regex stuff to achieve this goal.

My old config:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  example.com;

# allow large uploads of files - refer to nginx documentation
client_max_body_size 1G;

# optimize downloading files larger than 1G - refer to nginx doc 
before adjusting
#proxy_max_temp_file_size 2G;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://structure.example:80;
}

location /cdn {
    proxy_pass http://content.example:80;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

}
```

Stuff I tried:

```
    server {
listen       80;
server_name  example.com;

# allow large uploads of files - refer to nginx documentation
client_max_body_size 1G;

# optimize downloading files larger than 1G - refer to nginx doc 
before adjusting
#proxy_max_temp_file_size 2G;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://structure.nocms:80/index.html;
}

location ~* \S+ {
    proxy_pass http://structure.nocms:80;
}

location /cdn {
    proxy_pass http://content.nocms:80;
}



error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

}
```

Comment: Try adding `rewrite ^/$ /index.html last;` in your server block

Comment: @TarunLalwani Dosen't work unfortunately. But thank you anyway

Comment: So index.html needs to be served from disk `/usr/share/nginx/html` and not proxy passed to other urls?

Comment: @TarunLalwani No, index.html lies in http://structure.nocms:80/index.html. I copied the error handling...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below config should work for you

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  example.com;

# allow large uploads of files - refer to nginx documentation
client_max_body_size 1G;

# optimize downloading files larger than 1G - refer to nginx doc 
before adjusting
#proxy_max_temp_file_size 2G;

location = / {
    rewrite ^ /index.html permanent;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://structure.example:80;
}

location /cdn {
    proxy_pass http://content.example:80;
}

error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

}
```

Comment: do you need the browser URL also to change or just data to come from index.html?

Comment: Technically I only need the URL. I use `window.location.pathname` in js.

Answer (score 18):

The accepted answer has one disadvantage: going to **example.com** explicitly redirects to **example.com/index.html** (that is, returns `301 Moved permanently`), which is not always desired.

Instead, I suggest to prepend `location /` with another directive, `location = /`, which is designed to the root URL only:

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass http://structure.nocms:80/index.html;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://structure.nocms:80;
}
```

The above instructs nginx to pass requests to **example.com** directly to `http://structure.nocms:80/index.html`, while requesting any other URLs in **example.com/*** would pass the request to the corresponding URL in the downstream.

Comment: The second proxy_pass should end with a trailing slash

Comment: This is a _much_ better way of doing it, and something you most likely want to do as opposed to redirecting, especially with a 301 on your domain's root path.